# How to determine candidate keys from record schema and functional dependencies?

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra, functional-dependencies

If I have a schema say `R={A,B,C,D}` and functional dependencies say `{B->C, D->A}` will my set of candidate keys be `{B,D}` or `{BD}`?

Comment: Is this homework? If so then please tag it as such.

Comment: Yes, part of a question. I've answered it using {BD} but am having second thoughts

Comment: What do you think the difference is between {B,D} and {BD} ????

Comment: {BD} means that you need B AND D, where {B,D} means you need B OR D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If B were a candidate key, you'd have to be able to derive these functional dependencies from the ones given in the problem.

- {B->A}
- {B->C}
- {B->D}

Can you do that?

Comment: @SeanArnold: There's your answer.